# How can I find the percentage of times that a point in a 2D numpy array is greater than the corresponding point in a reference array, for all points?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Python newbie here. Given a list (`mylist`) of 2D numpy arrays, and a reference 2D numpy array (`refarr`), I'm looking for a way to create an array (`percentage_array`) in which each point (i,j) is the percentage of corresponding (i,j) points in the `mylist` arrays that are greater than [i,j] in `refarr`. I could do this by looping through all the points in the array and though the list, e.g.:

```
percentage_array = numpy.empty(arr.shape)
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        t = 0 
        f = 0
        for arr in mylist:
            if arr[i,j] > refarr[i,j]:
                t += 1 # counting the number of arrays for which [i,j] is true
            elif arr[i,j] <= refarr[i,j]:
                f += 1 # counting the number of arrays for which [i,j] is false
        percentage_array[i,j] = t/(t+f) # fraction of arrays which have 
                                        # arr[i,j] > refarr[i,j]
```

...but this is neither quick nor elegant (I'm dealing with large amounts of data). Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: It helps if you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a 3d array with

```
a = np.array(myList)
```

Then you can compare this array to your original one using broadcasting:

```
a < refarr # gives a 3D array of booleans because refarr is broadcasted to a 3D array
```

and to count the percentage of values where the condition is met, you average on the first axis:

```
(a < refarr[None, :, :]).mean(axis = 0)
```

The main drawback of this approach is that you have to create an array `a` which may be big. Otherwise I'd consider treating arrays one by one.

Comment: This gives an integer, not an array.

Comment: @ChloeG. I misread your question. You want to replace sum by mean(axis = 0)